# SQL Server logins and users -- assign multiple logins to a single user?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, security, ssms

In `SSMS`, since I can't assign multiple `login objects` to a single `user object`, what is a best practice to achieve an equivalent security model?

For example, I have `20 logins` and want to give them all the same permissions on a single database:

- Do I have to create 20 user objects in that database?
- Do I have to touch all 20 Login objects?

Comment: You can use a Windows group for the login, assign one user to the group, and then, outside SQL Server, assign Windows users to the group.  Alternately, you can use role-based permissions and assign the users to the role and assign the role the permissions it needs.  There's a [huge amount of depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510589.aspx) to the SQL Server security system.

Comment: @BaconBits I am not using Windows authentication. You may not have read the question: I have one User and 20 Login objects. Assigning permissions to the User object is not the issue. The issue is finding a Best Practice to assign multiple Login objects to a single User object or an equivalent strategy.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using SQL Server local logins, they cannot be grouped.  Each *login* is independent and each *login* needs a *user* in the database.

Where you can get some saving in specifying rights is to create *roles*, to which you `grant`, `revoke`, or `deny` rights.  (Note that `deny` rights override `grant` rights.)  Then use these *roles* to give rights to the users.

This way a *role* contains the specifications of permissions, rather than applying those to every *user* individually.

After this you can add the *users* to the *roles* that user needs.  For example:

- Allen - ReadOnly role
- Sally - ReadOnly role, MaintainAccounts role
- Zenubia - UpdateNonSecureData Role
- etc.

This preserves your security settings at the role level, so you should not need to repeat those grants.  Just add or remove a user from a role, when needed.

Answer (score 3):

Create a database role and add those users to the role (assuming as per the previous comment that you can't create an AD group). Grant permissions on the appropriate objects to the role.

```
create role MyRole

grant EXECUTE to MyRole    
-- or whatever permissions you want to give

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'MyRole', 'thisUser'    
-- add the relevant user name "thisUser" to the role "MyRole"
```

NB: you cannot map more than one "login" (server level) to a database "user" (db level) because each database user is created with a mapping to a specific server login. The model is fundamentally that a login in a database corresponds to 1 (*or 0 in the case of contained databases...*) server logins.

Edited to add: To make it more explicit - you have to create a database user for each of those logins (assuming you can't use windows authentication). But then you should give permissions via roles rather than individually if those 20 users are 'equivalent' with their security.